# Mylatexformat with a filename containing non-ascii characters like ä

Tags: ascii, mylatexformat

When I use a filename like ü.tex I have some problems to compile using mylatexformat, without mylatexformat everything is just fine.

I get an error:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.8.28) (preloaded format=mylatexformat 2022.12.16)  16 DEC 2022 18:14
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./ü.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> ./ü.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

My document:

```
%&C:\Test\mylatexformat
\endofdump
\begin{document}
Inhalt... 
\end{document}
```

Comment: And what is the contents of mylatexformat, and how did you compile that format?

Comment: contents of mylatexformat:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
d
\end{document}

Compiled with command:
etex -initialize "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx """Format.tex"""

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem. It is caused by the `mylatexformat` package that stores the filename as a macro name (there is a `\long\def^^M##1^^M{%` somewhere with `#1` being resolved to the filename/jobname). In pdfLaTeX it is not allowed to define commands with unicode characters in this way. You could either use xelatex/lualatex, or modify `mylatexformat` to fix this limitation, or use filenames with non-accented latin characters only.

Comment: @Marijn Is there a way to report this bug?

Comment: @ttsc the package is last updated in 2011, and from a 2019 update to the manual of another package by the same author (Florent Chervet) we learn that "Unfortunately the original author appears to be out of contact". So there is little chance of getting the bug fixed by reporting it. So somebody else needs to write the bugfix, and after that the options are to either post the fix here in this question on TeX.SE and hope that future users will find this page, or to take over the maintenance of the package on CTAN and upload a new version with the bug fixed for all users.